# statement to compare file name to file modified date

Tags: powershell, automation, renaming

I've been trying to write a PowerShell script to rename files in a directory to the ".LastWriteTime" property of the file.

I was originally looking to extract the EXIF "Date Taken" date, and use that, but I'm just trying to get the rest of the automation process first. Also, not all pictures have EXIF data, so using the .LastWriteTime is the next best thing.

```
$pictures = Get-ChildItem -path $picsdir\* -Include "*.jpg" | Sort {$_.LastWriteTime}
foreach ($picture in $pictures)
{
    $newfile = $picture.LastWriteTime | Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd-hhmmss"

    If ($picture.FullName -eq! "$picture.DirectoryName\$newfile.jpg" -And! (Test-Path -Path "$newfile.jpg"))
    {
        Rename-Item $picture.FullName -NewName $newfile$format
    }
}
```

Problem is I think I cant seem to correctly compare in the **If** statement, the difference between the existing file and current file. I'm doing this to further create logic for images that have the same date.

I'm stuck, I think, where I am trying to construct the path of the new file, using the **$picture.DirectoryName** of the current file.

Hoping someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "not equals" operator in PowerShell is `-ne` (not `-eq!`).

You don't need to compare the `FullName` property, you can use the `BaseName` property instead (the file name without extension):

```
if($picture.BaseName -ne $newfile)
{ 
    #Picture does not follow datetime naming
}
```

the other half of your if statement will also fail, as it will test for the file `"$newfile.jpg"` in the current directory, not in the directory where the picture exists. You can construct the full path with `Join-Path`:

```
Test-Path -Path (Join-Path $picture.Directory.FullName -ChildPath "$newfile.jpg")
```

Ending up with something like:

```
foreach ($picture in $pictures)
{
    $newName = $picture.LastWriteTime | Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd-hhmmss"
    $newFilePath = Join-Path $picture.Directory.FullName "$newName.jpg"

    if ($picture.BaseName -ne $newName -and -not(Test-Path -Path $newFilePath))
    {
        Rename-Item $picture.FullName -NewName "$newName.jpg"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is very useful.